# How to get a list of Strings (spring security roles) from a different table using two ids with hibernate annotations

Tags: hibernate, annotations, mapping

I have two tables like the following:

```
position
------------
position_id int(9)
company_id int(9)
description
...

authority
------------
position_id int(9)
company_id int(9)
role varchar
```

Inside my position object i have a `List<String> getRoles()` method. How would I annotate my `getRoles()` method to return the list of roles from my authority table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `@ElementCollection`. Read the [Hibernate reference manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#collections-ofvalues) for more information. It explains everything.